# Trying to reverse geocode to get zipcode, keep getting attribute error, any suggestions?

Tags: python, pandas, object, gis, attributeerror

I am trying to find zip codes for the locations in my dataframe. I have 3 locations and their latitudes and longitudes, which i've named lat and lon.

```
search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=True)
from uszipcode import Zipcode

def get_zipcode(lat, lon):
    result = search.by_coordinates(lat = lat, lng = lon, returns = 1).to_json()
    return result[1].zipcode
lat = noaa_df['lat']
lon = noaa_df['lon']

loc_df = pd.DataFrame({'lat':lat, 'lon':lon})

loc_df['zipcode'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_zipcode(x.lat,x.lon), axis=1)
```

I'm new to python and I'm using uszipcodes search engine function to reverse geocode from latitude and longitude to give zip code, and my end goal is to get zip codes for each location added into a new column in my dataframe. I keep getting this error, however:

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lat'`

Comment: Try to remove `axis=1` from your `df.apply` line

Comment: @PauloMarques I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that `df` was a Series, not a DataFrame. Also, the `.to_json()` method wasn't necessary.

Here's some code that should work:

```
from uszipcode import Zipcode, SearchEngine
import pandas as pd

lats = [34, 35, 36]
lons = [-98, -99, -99.5]
  
noaa_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lats, lons)),
                       columns =['lat', 'lon'])

search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=True)

def get_zipcode(lat, lon):
    result = search.by_coordinates(lat=lat, lng=lon)
    return result[1].zipcode

noaa_df['zipcode'] = noaa_df.apply(lambda x: get_zipcode(x.lat, x.lon), axis=1)
noaa_df
```

Note that the list of zip codes is zero-indexed, so the code above will pull the *second* zip code that meets the search criteria. The first zip code would be `result[0].zipcode`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to put a Series into a DataFrame.

Try this

```
loc_df['zipcode'] = loc_df['zipcode'].apply(lambda x: get_zipcode(x.lat,x.lon), axis=1)
```

Comment: `loc_df` doesn't appear to have a `zipcode` column, and you can't call apply on the column before it exists.